# Where can I find the ios/podfile in an expo project

Tags: expo, watermelondb

I am trying to get `watermelondb` working in my `expo` project with `sdk 45`. I am using `expo-dev-client` and building with `Expo Application Services (EAS)`. I have figured out that I need to install [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@morrowdigital/watermelondb-expo-plugin) and that I need the to apply [this patch](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB/pull/1249) to `watermelondb` to get it working with the latest `expo` sdk.

I have applied the patch in my own fork of `watermelondb` and have installed and setup the plugin. But I am confused by step 4 mentioned in the patch. The `watermelondb` patch says in step 4 that I need to add the following to `ios/Podfile`:

```
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'simdjson', path: '../node_modules/@nozbe/simdjson'
```

Where do I find this `ios/Podfile`? I can't seem to find it in my expo project. Or is this a file that I have to manually create? If so, what is the format of this file?

Answer (score 2):

In the android and ios folders is where the native code for both operating systems is located, they are available in "Bare Workflow" , you must eject from Expo Managed Workflow to Bare Workflow to get access to those folders.
Workflow reference: https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have since found out that you can get the iOS and android folders without ejecting using expo prebuild functionality. See here: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/